# Powershell script to Inventory File Types

Tags: powershell, hard-drive, export, csv, extension

I have been writing a script to inventory drives by specific file types.  (AVI, MPG, MP3, etc....)

I can get the base script to work using only a set drive and extension, but I would really like to have it read extensions from a file, and drives from a file.

```
$dir = get-childitem z:\ –recurse
ForEach ($item in $dir)
{
If ($item.extension –eq '.avi')
    {
    $item | select-object length,fullname,LastWriteTime | Export-CSV  C:\temp\z-avi.csv –notypeinformation –append
    }
}
```

When I search I am only finding server drivespace scripts.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want each disk to have a separate csv for each file type?  and is it running on multiple servers?

Comment: Two things to help: A `System.IO.FileInfo` object has an `Extension` property. You can group objects easily with `Group-Object`.

Comment: If it could seperate by drive, or at least include the dive letter, I could create a pivot table based upon the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messy but I went with WMI to get the drives and then looped through based on unique extensions:

```
$computer = Get-ADcomputer ComputerName
$drives = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $computer.DNSHostName | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.DriveLetter -ne $null -and $_.Label -ne "System Reserved"}

Foreach ($drive in $drives)
{
    $allfiles = gci $drive.DriveLetter -recurse | Select Name,FullName,Extension,Length,LastWriteTime
    $extensions = $allfiles | Select -Unique Extension
    Foreach ($ext in $extensions)
    {
    $filename = ($drive | Select -ExpandProperty DriveLetter -First 1)[0] +     ($ext | Select -ExpandProperty Extension -First 1)
    $extensionfiles = $allfiles | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq   $ext.extension}
    #$extensionfiles.count
    $extensionfiles | Export-Csv C:\Temp\$filename.csv -Notypeinformation
    }
}
```

The WMI call will bring back only local drives.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick... Please note the -WhatIf on the Export-Csv bit.

All csv-files would be saved under C:\temp in this example.

```
$drives = Get-Content .\Drives.txt
$extensions = Get-Content .\Extensions.txt

foreach($drive in $drives) 
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$drive`:\*" -Recurse -Include $($extensions | % { "*.$_" }) | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }
    $grouped = $files | Group-Object -Property Extension
    foreach ($group in $grouped)
    {
        $group | select -ExpandProperty Group | select Length, FullName, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\$drive-$($group.Name.Replace('.','')).csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Where Drives.txt has one drive letter per line

```
C
D
E
[...]
```

And Extensions.txt has one extension per line.

```
mp3
mpg
avi
[...]
```

Comment: I tried the previous code, and it does not output anything for me in the c:\temp\ folder.  I have edited the text files exactly like above, but still get the following message on files.

Get-ChildItem : Could not find item x:\Patient Education for Open Heart Surgery Patients Pre-op.docx.
At C:\Users\e32045\Desktop\files and sizes to csv with Variables.ps1:6 char:14
+     $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$drive`:\*" -Recurse -Include $($extensions |  ...

Comment: I assume you deleted the `-WhatIf` bit first. Anyway, it seem to work just fine for me, both with local and network paths. Could you try doing a `cd $drive` right before the Get-ChildItem line and see if that makes any difference?